# UILocalNotification is nil after app closes

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am working with UILocalNotifications. A problem I am having is that after I restart my app in XCode the data associated with a notification seems to be deleted. Here are the steps I am following.

-start the app in XCode

-receive the notification

-stop the app in XCode

-start the app in XCode

-go to notification center and tap on one of the notifications for my app

-break in `application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`

At this point if I inspect `notification` I find that it is `nil`.

Any ideas what is going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I am experiencing this as well. I can very reliably reproduce using the same steps

Answer (score 0):

If a local notification is tapped in notification center then app is started using the`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method and you can get access to the `UILocalNotification` object from the `options` dictionary by using the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`.

`application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` is only called if a notification fires and the app is in the foreground.

Comment: You are answering case when notification is nil ?

Comment: In the flow streaker describes, the app is running when he taps the notification from the notification center.